# Emberdata Models dont seem to get populated with the response

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make a simple file browser app, but it is giving me a real headache. I've tried to port it into a jsfiddle with a FixtureAdapter: http://jsfiddle.net/Rolus/bB2mr/23/

(I'm not sure if i have defined the fixtures correctly in the fiddle, it's the first time i use this adapter.)

What I'm trying to make the app do (in the router) is make a request to the server for a 'root' file (directory) which contains 3 'child' files. The server then returns a response with those 3 'child' files:

```
{
    "file":{
        "uri":"L3Rlc3QvdGVzdDA=",
        "size":1000,
        "children":["dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0MS5ibGE=",
                    "dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0Mi5ibGE=",
                    "dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0My5ibGE="]
    }
}
```

(URI's are base64 encoded.) I then ask it to get the children and the app makes a second request (as expected) which returns the following response:

```
{
    "files" : [
        {
            "uri":"dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0MS5ibGE=",
            "size":1,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "uri":"dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0Mi5ibGE=",
            "size":2,
            "children":[]
        },
        {
            "uri":"dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0My5ibGE=",
            "size":3,
            "children":[]
        }]
}
```

However, during this process i noticed two things:

First: even though the 'root' model seems to know about its 'children' (it makes the request i expect it to make) it does not seem to know about its own 'uri' or 'size', because adding this didLoad method to the model:

```
didLoad: function () {
    console.log("id: "+ this.id + " " + this.get("uri") + this.get("size"));
}
```

Results in the following being printed to the console:

```
id: L3Rlc3QvdGVzdDA= nullnull
```

Secondly it seems to ignore my efforts to change the primary key to 'uri' `DS.JSONSerializer._primaryKey(App.File)` returns 'id'. I'm trying several different ways to change the primaryKey in the model.

After making the second request 3 more didLoad lines get output to the console:

```
id: dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0MS5ibGE= nullnull
id: dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0Mi5ibGE= nullnull
id: dGVzdC90ZXN0MC90ZXN0My5ibGE= nullnull
```

And my view gets updated with 3 empty lines ("Filename: ", see the template in the fiddle) but it never gets populated with response data.

At this point the script finally runs into an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError ('hash' undefined): Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of null ember-data.js:6246
    DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.extractId
```

Which seems to be caused by a 4th iteration of JSONSerializer after the second response, while there are only 3 items in the response array so on the 4th iteration 'hash' is obviously null, the question is why it does a 4th iteration at all.

I hope my ramblings here are making some sense. It's probably easiest to just look at the fiddle. I'm really hoping someone can spot some errors in it because I've really ran out of ideas.

Im using emberjs v1.0.0-pre.2-123-ga352c48 and ember-data revision 11.

Thanks in advance.